# RabbitMQ Exception An unexpected connection driver error occured

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ message broker as messaging service. I have seen this error 3-4 times in the past 10 days.

c.r.c.i.ForgivingExceptionHandler in RabbitMQ Error On Write Thread - An unexpected connection driver error occured

This is the only stacktrace i could see. No other information found. what could be the reasons for this error?

```
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1 [error] c.r.c.i.ForgivingExceptionHandler in RabbitMQ Error On Write Thread - An unexpected connection driver error occured
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1554)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1566)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.flush(SocketFrameHandler.java:197)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.flush(AMQConnection.java:573)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:134)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:455)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:434)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingRpc(AMQChannel.java:351)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:614)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:547)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:540)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1924)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1888)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1833)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:128)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.flush(SocketFrameHandler.java:197)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.HeartbeatSender$HeartbeatRunnable.run(HeartbeatSender.java:140)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Sept 15 19:19:13 test-env app/w.1   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
```

Comment: `Connection reset` is the information of interest. 

I would guess at a firewall shutting your connection down.  Also, the other end could have shut you down.  Common reasons are timeout and data volumes. Interesting information you could add to this question would be if there is any consistency in up-time, size of message, interval between this error message.